# type keyword in scala file upload exampe

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

`type FilePartHandler[A] = FileInfo => Accumulator[ByteString, FilePart[A]]`

```
def handleFilePartAsFile: FilePartHandler[File] = {
    case FileInfo(partName, filename, contentType) =>
    val perms = java.util.EnumSet.of(OWNER_READ, OWNER_WRITE)
    val attr = PosixFilePermissions.asFileAttribute(perms)
    val path = Files.createTempFile("multipartBody", "tempFile", attr)
    val file = path.toFile
    val fileSink = FileIO.toFile(file)
    val accumulator = Accumulator(fileSink)
    accumulator.map { case IOResult(count, status) =>
      FilePart(partName, filename, contentType, file)
    }(play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.defaultContext)
}
```

I have copied the above code from Play file upload example. I am having a hard time with syntax of `type`keyword. If I say something like this
`type mytype = Int => String`. I can use it say like below

```
def method2(f:mytype) = "20"
def f(v:Int) = "hello"
method2(f)
```

But I based on whatever I understand, I am at total loss of how the following syntax is being used in the method `handleFilePartAsFile` and what does it even mean?

```
type FilePartHandler[A] = FileInfo => Accumulator[ByteString, FilePart[A]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is exactly the same. You just have a type parameter (like you've probably seen on classes and methods before) which can be substituted by any type, so e.g. `FilePartHandler[File]` is `FileInfo => Accumulator[ByteString, FilePart[File]]` and you could write `handleFilePartAsFile` as

```
def handleFilePartAsFile: FileInfo => Accumulator[ByteString, FilePart[File]] = { ...
```

You can think of type synonyms with parameters as functions from types to types.

Comment: In plane english does it mean "handleFilePartsAsFile" is a method that takes another method(whether named or anonymous) and the input to that method is "FileInfo" with output as Accumulator...?
And if what I wrote above is correct, then in the example at hand, we are writing a method "handleFilePartAsFile" whose block is an anonymous function that satisfies the above criteria I wrote?

Comment: No, it's a method which _returns_ a function (not a method), and the input to that function is `FileInfo`. And `{ case FileInfo(...) => ... }` defines such a function.

Comment: yes i worded it wrong, so elaborating on what you wrote,    ``handleFilePartAsFile`` is a method. This handleFilePartsAsFile  returns a function. It is this function that takes FileInfo as an input and returns Accumulator as an output?

Comment: @curiousengineer Yes.

Comment: respects to you. You are amazing! Thanks